# How to override the max-width of <v-container>

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, nuxt3, vuetifyjs3

I have configured Sass variables to override the max-width of Vuetify's `<v-container>` as follows:

```
@use 'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass' with (
  $body-font-family: $body-font-family,
  $container-max-widths: (
    'md': 1190px,
    'lg': 1190px,
    'xl': 1190px,
    'xxl': 1190px,
  )
);
```

https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site/blob/main/assets/main.scss

However, currently, the max-width is not being applied, and the width exceeds 1190px. The current state can be seen here:

https://document-driven-demo.netlify.app/ja/getting-started/introduction/

The full application code can be found here:

https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site/tree/main

I'm seeking advice as I'm unable to identify the cause of the issue.

**Here's an addition:**

I was able to override the following variables, but for some reason, I couldn't override $container-max-widths:

```
$border-style-root: dotted;
$border-color-root: blue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Into your [nuxtConfig](https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site/blob/0bfeb871a63651bb0fef26106fbc29ec7fb5cb5d/nuxt.config.ts#L11), configure vuetify with the `styles.configFile` option as

```js
hooks: {
  'vite:extendConfig': (config) => {
    config.plugins!.push(vuetify({
      styles: {
        configFile: "styles/settings.scss"
      }
    }));
  },
}
```

And override the vuetify style variables from `styles/settings.scss`

```scss
@use "vuetify/settings" with (
  $body-font-family: "Comic Sans",
  $button-height: 80px,
  $container-max-widths: (
  'md': '1190px',
  'lg': '1190px',
  'xl': '1190px',
  'xxl': '1190px',
  )
);
```

Note: Vuetify should be above `3.3.1`. [Issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/17419#issuecomment-1561156596)

Reference: See the `Style Loading` section at https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-vuetify

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried adding the Vuetify configuration to nuxt.config.ts, but it resulted in an error. Also, in the current code, when I added $border-color-root: red; to the main.scss file, the border color turned red.

Comment: I have added to the main text, but I was able to override the following variables, but I couldn't override $container-max-widths:
``$border-style-root: dotted;
$border-color-root: blue;``

Comment: Can you show what was the issue (error message)?

Comment: I'm sorry. I should have also mentioned the error message. The error that occurred when I added to nuxt.config.ts is as follows:

``Cannot restart nuxt: ParseError: C:: Unexpected keyword 'true'.
C:/Users/9004084208/nuxt-site/nuxt.config.ts:8:16``

Comment: Try removing the `autoImport key:value`. I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you.
As you mentioned in your response, I made the addition to nuxt.config.ts.

https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site/blob/feature/override-sass-variables/nuxt.config.ts#L114

However, I encountered the following warning, and the page is not displayed
``WARN Sourcemap for "plugin-vuetify:components/VSelect/VSelect.sass" points to missing source files`` ``WARN  Sourcemap for "plugin-vuetify:components/VMain/VMain.sass" points to missing source files``

Comment: After adding 'autoImport: true' to the Vuetify configuration, I was able to override the variables.

Comment: The warning hasn't disappeared, but I was able to override the variables. Your response was helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: strange, i thought it was giving error before, anyway, cheers! it's good that the target is accomplished